# Unmarshal struct into string including comments

Tags: go, yaml

I want to partially read a yaml, i.e. decode `Type`/`Description` keys but keep the `Sample` key- which defines a struct- as plain string. Purpose is to define test data sets for decoding.

Example:

```
type: default
description: test data
sample:
  some: # want
    complex: # comments
    - struct # included
```

I would want the subkey of `sample` to be returned as plain string.

I've tried using an alias type with unmarshaler interface (`gopkg.in/yaml.v2`):

```
type plain string // implements UnmarshalYAML
```

but end with:

```
panic: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 4: cannot unmarshal !!map into []uint8
```

I couldn't find a simple way for doing this with either `UnmarshalYAML` and a custom string type or coercing into string?

Comment: Please include an example input (yaml) and indicate what you want as the result. Also post what you've tried so far and what yaml library you're using.

Comment: sorry for the unclear question, expanded as requested. would be nice to do with with the yaml parser instead of pattern matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be aware that by reading comments, you are violating the YAML spec, which explicitly says comments must not convey content information.

Anyway, go-yaml v3 supplies the type `yaml.Node` for intermediate substructures:

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type file struct {
  Type string
  Description string
  Sample yaml.Node
}

var input []byte = []byte(`
type: default
description: test data
sample:
  some: # want
    complex: # comments
    - struct # included
`)

func main() {
  var f file
  var err error
  if err = yaml.Unmarshal(input, &f); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  var out []byte
  if out, err = yaml.Marshal(&f.Sample); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

This prints

```yaml
some: # want
    complex: # comments
      - struct # included
```

It works by storing the structure into a `yaml.Node`, which does store the comments. It then renders the node as standalone YAML document.

You can access the comments by walking through the node structure.

The string is not identical to the original string since YAML always loses some information when it is being loaded. If you have the requirement of getting the value with exact spacing, you do need to encode the subtree as literal block scalar like you showed in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I've modified my approach by defining `sample` as string in the yaml:

```
type: default
description: test data
sample: |
  some: # want
    complex: # comments
    - struct # included
```

It's more a workaround, but a simple one...